# Desktop screen capture in web application

Tags: javascript, php, electron

How can a web service app capture the video stream of a user's view such as the desktop screen, to use in my web application ( which has a backend running php for example and javascript client side). Is this possible and using which approach can this data feed be instantiated and pipelined?

Comment: Do you mean the browser window ?!

Comment: Have you maybe tried googling for "js screenshot"?

Comment: @Luca, I tried it more and more, `JS Screenshot` just capture screenshot from the browser or electron face not all the desktop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capture screenshot of parts of the client "desktop" using HTML/JavaScript ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34723564/how-to-capture-screenshot-of-parts-of-the-client-desktop-using-html-javascript)

Comment: Maybe this might help. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-take-screenshot-using-jquery-and-php/

Comment: Refer https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-screen-share/

Comment: the user needs to grant permissions first, `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video: true }).then((stream) => {// put the stream on a video tag })`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible at all, because `PHP` is server side and does not related to client desktop, and absolutely `JavaScript` run in browser or `electron` environment which both of them are separated from `OS` environment, the `JavaScript` code are run in closed environment so it is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has full access to the document object model, so at least in theory, it could capture what's on its own web page (but not anything outside the browser window) and there's a library to do that: [http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com) (I haven't tried it.)

Answer (score 1):

An [electron](https://electronjs.org/) application can make use of the [desktopCapturer](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/desktop-capturer) API to take a screenshot of the screen.

A demonstration (with code) is available in the [Electron API Demos](https://github.com/electron/electron-api-demos) application. You can [download the latest release](https://github.com/electron/electron-api-demos/releases) for your operating system or build it yourself.

Renderer process:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const desktopCapturer = electron.desktopCapturer
const electronScreen = electron.screen
const shell = electron.shell

const fs = require('fs')
const os = require('os')
const path = require('path')

const screenshot = document.getElementById('screen-shot')
const screenshotMsg = document.getElementById('screenshot-path')

screenshot.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  screenshotMsg.textContent = 'Gathering screens...'
  const thumbSize = determineScreenShotSize()
  let options = { types: ['screen'], thumbnailSize: thumbSize }

  desktopCapturer.getSources(options, function (error, sources) {
    if (error) return console.log(error)

    sources.forEach(function (source) {
      if (source.name === 'Entire screen' || source.name === 'Screen 1') {
        const screenshotPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'screenshot.png')

        fs.writeFile(screenshotPath, source.thumbnail.toPng(), function (error) {
          if (error) return console.log(error)
          shell.openExternal('file://' + screenshotPath)
          const message = `Saved screenshot to: ${screenshotPath}`
          screenshotMsg.textContent = message
        })
      }
    })
  })
})

function determineScreenShotSize () {
  const screenSize = electronScreen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize
  const maxDimension = Math.max(screenSize.width, screenSize.height)
  return {
    width: maxDimension * window.devicePixelRatio,
    height: maxDimension * window.devicePixelRatio
  }
}
```